# Extjs4 Clollapsible panel height

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I use extjs 4 and I want to create collapsible right panel but not as the height as the main container. I tried bodyStyle: 'background:transparent', but it doesn't work. hee is what I got:
[image]

```
  { xtype:'panel',
                 id: 'app-options',
                 region: 'east',
                 bodyStyle: 'background:transparent',
                 cls:'my-panel',
                 frame:false,
                 boder:false,
                 width: 200,
                 collapsible: true,

                 layout:{type:'border'
                },
                 items: [{
                        xtype:'panel',
                        region: 'north',
                        title: 'Test',
                       height:200

                    }
                  ]
                }
```

How can I make the blue area transparent? I need the map to be appeared instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting a js error with the current code or you haven't shared the complete code.
Because, the code which you posted here :

```
layout:{type:'border'
                },
                 items: [{
                        xtype:'panel',
                        region: 'north',
                        title: 'Test',
                       height:200

                    }
                  ]
```

It has a border layout without a center region at all !
So according to border layout center region is a must. And I couldn't see the code which you are putting for map to load in east panel.